# Why doesn't a milestone show 100% complete based on predecessor when all tasks are completed for the section?

Tags: ms-project

I have four tasks in a section with a milestone. The first three tasks completed by baseline dates and the fourth was delayed a few days. When the fourth task completed, the milestone that depended on the task didn't change to 100% complete. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Milestones, like any other task, must be statused independently. Just because it is linked the % Complete will not automatically be updated.